# Creating LTSpice Component based on IBIS data (MAX3232e RS-232 Line Driver/ Receiver)

Tags: integrated-circuit, ltspice, simulation, ibis

is there any possibility to convert the IBIS-data of the RS-232 Line Driver/Receiver MAX3232E into a working LTSpice model **by hand** so that it can be added into circuit diagram /schematic? All necessary information can be found here: https://www.ti.com/lit/mo/sllm062/sllm062.zip?ts=1696514426253  (There are two models- the one I need runs with 5 volt Vcc)

Comment: Note that IBIS only models pins; one cannot model the function of a device this way.

Comment: So basically if I wanted to use a functioning model of the line driver I need a proper Spice model including all internal circuitry data because the IBIS data doesn´t provide enough data for an analysis within a circuit (Transient, AC Sweep, etc.)?

Comment: Right. Granted, an interface is pretty basic, it's not like it's hard to fill in the internal logic (it's practically wires), but it depends how much detail you want out of it too, for example you're almost certainly not going to get a model of charge pump pins/logic (they're "NC" in the IBIS model), you'd have to characterize and build that entirely yourself. It's also not clear what value you'd get, nor expect, from an AC model of one; with schmitt triggers around, AC is not meaningful. It's not clear what importance a transient model is, either; it's a very simple function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LT spice doesn't have the ability to simulate ibis directly.

Try using this IBIS to spice converter, it works for any spice package as it converts ibis to a subcircuit file. http://www.spisim.com/blog/ibis2spice_p1/